# Laravel - How to create user control in Laravel base role

Tags: laravel

Hello I'm a newbie with Laravel, I wanna ask how to make user control in Laravel base user role,

I have 5 table

- table menus

[image]

- table user_menus

[image]

- table roles

[image]

- table user_roles

[image]

- table users

[image]

and then I want to validate which user can access the menu
the example role_id 1 (administrator) can access menu 1 and 2 ('master maintenance' and 'user')

and if authentication then can access the module, if not then redirect to 404.

Please help me! I have no idea what should I do :(

I looking for many sites but I don't get any solution

Thanks for answer

Comment: When it comes to roles and permission, you could try using https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust

Answer (score 0):

I not sure because i don't have your database but i think you and set relation in you model for make it easy

in model UserRole add relation

```
public function usermenus()
{
    return $this->hasMany('UserMenus', 'role_id', 'role_id');
}
```

in model UserMenus add relation

```
public function menus()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Menus', 'menu_id', 'menu_id');
}
```

when you want to query data

```
$menus = UserRole::where('user_id', $userId)->with('usermenus.menus')->get()->toArray();

print_r($menus); exit;
//or use dd($menus); for print and die
```